# If $G/G’ $ is cyclic, prove by induction that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic if $G$ is $p$ group.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, quotient-group, p-groups, derived-subgroup

> Let $G$ be a $p$ group. If $G/G’$ is cyclic, prove $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic by induction.

I tried playing with the base cases : if $|G|=p $ or $p^2$, $G $ is abelian, so $G/Z(G)=G/G =\{G\}$ which is generated by $1G$.

If $|G|=p^3$, the center is non trivial (because it is a p-group). If $Z(G)=p^3$, $G/Z(G)=\{1G\}$ which is cyclic. If $Z(G)=p^2$, we get $G/Z(G)$ having order $p$ and being cyclic, which implies an abelian $G$. This is absurd. If $Z(G)=p$, $G/Z(G)$ is abelian so $G’\subset Z(G)$. Because $G$ is non abelian the comutator is non trivial and by Lagrange’s theorem $|G’|=p\Rightarrow Z(G)=G’$ so $G/Z(G)=G/G’$ is cyclic.

This doesn’t seem to generalize nicely. Any ideas on the inductive step?

Comment: This is not stronger. If $G$ is abelian, then $G/Z(G)$ is trivial!

Comment: Thanks. This seems to do the trick. But I haven’t studied the Frattini group…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good work so far! Here's one way to run the inductive step:

Suppose $G/G'$ is cyclic. The canonical projection $G \to G/Z(G)$ is surjective and sends commutators to commutators, so it descends to a surjective homomorphism $G/G' \to (G/Z(G))/(G/Z(G))'$. Since $G/G'$ is cyclic, $(G/Z(G))/(G/Z(G))'$ must be cyclic as well.

Now $G/Z(G)$ is a $p$-group of strictly smaller cardinality (because $G$ has nontrivial center), so we can conclude (by inductive hypothesis) that $(G/Z(G))/Z(G/Z(G))$ is cyclic.

This implies that $G/Z(G)$ is abelian, by a standard argument.

Now this means that the canonical projection $G \to G/Z(G)$ factors through $G/G'$. Now we have a surjective homomorphism from the cyclic group $G/G'$ to $G/Z(G)$, so $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic.

Comment: Could you please explain what this epimorphism from $G/G’$ to $G/Z(G)/(G/Z(G))’$ looks like? I am not sure I understand what you mean by the fact it descends to an epimorphism.

Comment: Explicitly, we send a coset $xG'$ to the coset $(xZ(G))(G/Z(G))'$.

Comment: If $xG’=yG’$, we have $y=x g’$. This implies $$y Z(G) (G/Z(G))’=x g’ Z(G)(G/Z(G))’= xZ(G) g’ Z(G)(G/Z(G))’=xZ(G) (G/Z(G))’$$    So it is well defined! Thank you. I would have never thought about this on my own. How did you think of such a homomorphism?

Comment: About your final step, here is a different way to do this: if $G/Z(G)$ is abelian, $G’\subset Z(G)$, so $(G/G’)/(Z(G)/G’)\approx G/Z(G)$. Because $G/G’$ is cyclic, $ (G/G’)/(Z(G)/G’)$ will be cyclic.

Comment: In general, if $f : G \to H$ is a homomorphism, then there is a well-defined homomorphism $G/G' \to H/H'$ given by $xG' \mapsto f(x)H'$. I applied this in the case that $f$ is the canonical projection $G \to G/Z(G)$.